# Servicestack: Handle indexes, auto increment etc without attributes?

Tags: c#, mysql, ormlite-servicestack

I am testing [OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite), and I am looking at how to handle indexes in the tables that are created.

The only way that I have found if you want to mark something as an index, unique, auto_increment etc is via attributes, like this:

```
Index(Unique = true)] // Creates Unique Index
public string Email { get; set; }
```

However, OrmLite/ServiceStack states that:

> - Map a POCO class 1:1 to an RDBMS table, cleanly by conventions, without any attributes required.

And I was thus hoping that there are other ways of defining these things without using attributes? The library with the class definitions should be completely separated from OrmLite.

Is this doable?

---

EDIT:

The extension method AddAttributes does not seem to function for some reason:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention, means that OrmLite will infer the schema from the model as can be expected. But if you want to add any customizations like adding an index on arbitrary fields, than you do need to tell OrmLite about them. As OrmLite is a code-first ORM, attributes are how to decorate additional functionality to your models.

In the next **OrmLite v4** you will be able to add these attributes decoupled from your POCO by adding them dynamically at startup, e.g:

```
typeof(Poco).GetProperty("Email")
    .AddAttributes(new IndexAttribute { Unique = true });
```

Which will have the same effect as decorating your property with `[Index(Unique = true)]`

Comment: Ok, so the first point is not entirely correct until v 4 is available. Is there any info in release date there?

Comment: @Ted Evaluation of v4 is currently [available on MyGet](https://plus.google.com/+DemisBellot/posts/NxHUpV1sg1d), it will be publicly released on NuGet towards the end of this month.

Comment: @Ted Here's a [recent status update](https://plus.google.com/+DemisBellot/posts/Sbd5113dRrd). This API unit test shows a lot of [what the API looks like in v4](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/ApiSqlServerTests.cs). We'll work on the docs after the v4-beta release.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick answer. To bug you (or someone else) a little more; it doesnt seem to work with the AddAttributes, that method does not exist for PropertyInfo (that GetProperty returns). How is this supposed to work?

Comment: @Ted With the extension methods that are in `ServiceStack.Text`. In v4, you can add attributes decoupled from the code-first POCOs at Startup like this for all ServiceStack attributes.

Comment: Thanks, but I added the "using ServiceStack.Text;" to the top, but the AddAttributes won't show up, as I expect it to. The DLL version for ServiceStack.Text is 4.0.17.0 and its referenced in the project. I updated the question to show this.

Comment: @Ted Most common extension methods are in the `ServiceStack` namespace. If you've got ReSharper, it will let you know where it is and auto-reference namespaces for you.

Comment: Ok, "using ServiceStack;" worked, it wasn't ServiceStack.Text is seems. Thanks for your help (please write an "answer" and Ill accept that) =) Maybe you can help me here too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891992/servicestack-attribues-for-indexes-not-working

Comment: @mythz  where can i find the source code of the v4 please ? i want to have a look on the AddAttributes extension method