# ServiceStack.OrmLite: Where to add runtime attributes (instead of inline/design-time attributes)?

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Some 4 years ago, I [asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884733/servicestack-handle-indexes-auto-increment-etc-without-attributes). I then decided not to use OrmLite at that point, but I am back at it now again.

This time, I would like to know where I add the code for adding runtime attributes? I tried as below, but the runtime attributes does not appear.

What am I missing?

```html
public ActorNotificationDbHandler()
{
    DbAccount dbAccount = DBAccounts[0];
    SetTableMeta();

    _dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory($"Uid={dbAccount.Username};Password={dbAccount.Password};Server={dbAccount.Address};Port={dbAccount.Port};Database={dbAccount.Database}", MySqlDialect.Provider);
    _db = _dbFactory.Open();

    if (_db.CreateTableIfNotExists<ActorNotification>())
    {
        _db.Insert(new ActorNotification { CreatedTime = DateTime.Now, ToActor = 123, Status = ActorNotification.ActorNotificationStatuses.Created });
        _db.Insert(new ActorNotificationMessage { ActorNotificationId = 1, MessageState = ActorNotificationMessage.MessageStates.Created });
    }

    var result = _db.SingleById<ActorNotification>(1);
    result.PrintDump(); //= {Id: 1, Name:Seed Data}
}

private void SetTableMeta()
{
    typeof(ActorNotification).GetProperty("Id").AddAttributes(new IndexAttribute { Unique = true }, new AutoIncrementAttribute());
    typeof(ActorNotification).GetProperty("ToActor").AddAttributes(new IndexAttribute { Unique = false });
    typeof(ActorNotification).GetProperty("CoreObjectId1").AddAttributes(new IndexAttribute { Unique = false });
    typeof(ActorNotification).GetProperty("CoreObjectId2").AddAttributes(new IndexAttribute { Unique = false });
    typeof(ActorNotification).GetProperty("Status").AddAttributes(new IndexAttribute { Unique = false });
    typeof(ActorNotification).GetProperty("CreatedTime").AddAttributes(new IndexAttribute { Unique = false });

    typeof(ActorNotificationMessage).GetProperty("Id").AddAttributes(new IndexAttribute { Unique = true }, new AutoIncrementAttribute());
    typeof(ActorNotificationMessage).GetProperty("ActorNotificationId").AddAttributes(new IndexAttribute { Unique = false });
    typeof(ActorNotificationMessage).GetProperty("FrontEndServerHandler").AddAttributes(new IndexAttribute { Unique = false });
    typeof(ActorNotificationMessage).GetProperty("TimeCreated").AddAttributes(new IndexAttribute { Unique = false });
    typeof(ActorNotificationMessage).GetProperty("TimeStatusChanged").AddAttributes(new IndexAttribute { Unique = false });
    typeof(ActorNotificationMessage).GetProperty("MessageState").AddAttributes(new IndexAttribute { Unique = false });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As so many times before, I find the answer after I post the question. But, maybe it will help someone else.

Solution:
Move the SetTableMet() to AFTER creating the Db factory and db:

```html
public ActorNotificationDbHandler()
{
    DbAccount dbAccount = Core.Server.SRefCoreServer.dbHandler.DBAccounts[0];
            
    _dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory($"Uid={dbAccount.Username};Password={dbAccount.Password};Server={dbAccount.Address};Port={dbAccount.Port};Database={dbAccount.Database}", MySqlDialect.Provider);
    _db = _dbFactory.Open();
    SetTableMeta();

    if (_db.CreateTableIfNotExists<ActorNotification>())
    {
        _db.Insert(new ActorNotification { CreatedTime = DateTime.Now, ToActor = 123, Status = ActorNotification.ActorNotificationStatuses.Created });
        _db.Insert(new ActorNotificationMessage { ActorNotificationId = 1, MessageState = ActorNotificationMessage.MessageStates.Created });
    }

    var result = _db.SingleById<ActorNotification>(1);
    result.PrintDump(); //= {Id: 1, Name:Seed Data}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You normally don't have to do this (as it's called automatically when using any stand-alone ServiceStack library), but if you're adding runtime attributes you need to ensure ServiceStack.Text static contructor is called by either calling [JsConfig.InitStatics()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/05e11cb2e7c5413f55cae2f51dbb8594208e32f2/src/ServiceStack.Text/JsConfig.cs#L26) manually, e.g:

```
private void SetTableMeta()
{
    JsConfig.InitStatics();
    //...
}
```

Otherwise `OrmLiteConnectionFactory` also calls it in its constructor so you can initialize the any runtime attributes after initializing `__dbFactory`, e.g:

_dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(...);
   SetTableMeta();

```
_db = _dbFactory.Open();
```

Comment: Sorry, I didnt follow this. JsConfig? Called automatically? SetTableMeta() can be after dbFactory, but doesnt really matter if its after .Open I guess? =)

Comment: @Ted Yes it can be after _dbFactory or _db